# django-autocomplete-light, widget attributes, no placeholder visible

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've implemented autocomplete in my form: 
`related_groups = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=UserGroup.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
            url='groups-autocomplete',
            attrs={
                'data-placeholder': 'Autocomplete ...',
                'data-minimum-input-length': 2,
            },
        )
    )`
    
Generally, autosuggesting works but the placeholder and minimum input lenght don't (groups-autocomplete is my alias to my view).
Are these fields properly written here? I found such an example in official tutorial available [here](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html): 
 . 
 Am i missing something here? I'm really confused about that.

Comment: I added attrs in init block and now i works, however no idea why:
`self.fields['related_groups'].widget.attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control form-control-lg',
            'data-placeholder': '  type groups here...',
            'data-minimum-input-length': 2,
        }`